# How can I circular shift a submatrix of a matrix in Matlab

Tags: matlab, matrix, sparse-matrix

Lets say I have a K-matrix of size [5x5] in Matlab whose all elements are ones. Now I have a second P-matrix of size [25x25] whose all elements are zeros. The first M rows and N columns of P is now updated with K's element.

```
M = 5;
N = 5;
K = ones(M,N);
P = zeros(M*N, M*N);
P(1:M,1:N) = K;
```

Now, I want to make the matrix P as circulant matrix. That is the submatrix (K) of P will shift circularly to right. What is the best way to do this in Matlab.

Comment: [circshift function](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/circshift.html)

Comment: Yes, thanks. If I do circshift(P,[M,N]) the submatrix K is shifted towards right. But how do I repeatedly do this for the whole matrix such that not only the diagonals of the matrix is created with K but the loop goes over until full matrix is covered.

Comment: Sorry, I don't understand what you're asking for. It might help if you posted some example input/expected output matrices.

Comment: @SAM Please post an example of your expected output.